# Salesforce SOQL querying negative currency fields in multi currency orgs

Tags: soql, multi-currency

Based on salesforce [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm) currency based where clauses are of the form: WHERE Object_name Operator ISO_CODEvalue

Sample query would look like:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount > USD5000
```

See the USD before 5000 to specify the currency. But the documentation doesn't describe how to deal with negative values.

I have tried followings and all of them fail with parsing error from salesforce.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount > USD-5000
```

and

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount > -USD5000
```

which throws:

> ```
> {
>     "message": "\nName FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount > -USD5000\n                                      ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:49\nunexpected token: 'USD5000'",
>     "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
> }
> ```

What is the proper way of using ISO_CODEvalue for currency fields when the query requires negative values?

Based on comment below, I have also tried following query:

```
 SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount >-1*USD5000
```

Salesforce throws following exception:

> ```
> {
>     "message": "\nFROM Opportunity WHERE Amount >-1*USD5000\n                                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:49\nunexpected token: '*'",
>     "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
> }
> ```

Note: [I have previously asked this question in stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510775/salesforce-soql-querying-currency-fields-in-multi-currency-orgs%20/%22I%20have%20previously%20asked%20this%20question%20in%20stackoverflow.%22)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson. Updated the question with appropriate links. Yes, I did try -1*USD5000, it fails with same query parsing error.

Comment: Updated the question to include -1* approach and salesforce responses.

Comment: I don't have an org with multi-currency at the moment. Have you tried using () around the value? For example: -(USD5000) or USD(-5000).

Comment: @Stephen both result in same "MALFORMED_QUERY" response from salesforce.

Comment: using the () results in an error. You can query < USD0.00 but you do not get specific records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a support ticket and talking with salesforce support, the conclusion is that they don't support this functionality.

> Create a currency field, in a workflow field update set it to -amount. Use
>   this in the query.
>
> To get the negative values, i.e
>   Amount > -USD500
>
> Could be written like this...
>
> NegativeAmount__c < USD500 OR Amount >= USD0

It's similar to workaround we knew also suggested by @Eric.
Although it works fine, it's not a scalable solution if you are running query against arbitrary field/object. Below is the response we got when we stated the solution is not feasible for us.

> I understand that the solution provided is not feasible for you. 
>   Currently, Salesforce does not have an option of adding "-ve" signs in the query for Currency values. I highly recommend you to post this request on our Idea Exchange board to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this helps or not but this appears to work although it does not seem to take into account conversions, at least I do not think so:

```
> -10.00 and CurrencyISOCode = 'CAD'
```

You can also query

```
< USD0.00
```

but obviously the records returned are not specific to an amount you may be looking for

All other attempts I tried failed with query errors.

A slight workaround maybe:

1. Create two fields

   - Currency
   - Checkbox
2. WFR to populate the currency field with the ABS value of the main currency field
3. WFR to set the checkbox to true if the amount in the new currency field should be negative

then query the new currency field `[>, <, =] CAD10.00` and [CheckBox] = true`

Maybe as a workaround?

Comment: If you had to go down this route, you could do the conversion yourself, couldn't you?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I would assume so, but I am no expert on the multi-currency so do not have the knowledge to offer a solid answer on that.

Comment: To implement expected behavior of field > -USD5000 using this technique will involve finding out all the supported currencies, use the exchange rate to convert and construct OR clauses of the from (amount > -10.00 and CurrencyISOCode = 'CAD') OR (> -7.60 and CurrencyISOCode = 'USD') OR.... I believe this would create massive where clause, combining with other constraints probably will exceed the query size limit for REST APIS.

Comment: @Mahesh - Yes, but what else are you left with at this point. You could do the processing in code after you retrieve results. Until the ability to query a specific negative amount with ISO code I do not see many other options

Comment: @Mahesh - You could get creative, create a currency field that will always be positive, use a WFR to populate it. Create a checkbox that indicates negative, then use that field to query

Comment: @Eric thanks for your suggestions. It's very hard to get any changes in SFDC schema implemented for some of the clients I'm working with. I will see if > -10.00 and CurrencyISOCode = 'CAD' type of approach is feasible. Also, I'll check with salesforce to see if they plan to fix this.

Comment: this calls for use of the Doc feedback feature and request an example be added on how to do this

Comment: @cropredy They actually responded last time I used that feature.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - really -- I have submitted at least 15 and never heard once.  You must be using the 'please' word

Answer (score 0):

One way to query negative currency field is to create a `formula field` of type `currency` to populate positive value of the currency field. It works for all currencies.

So in this case you can create a formula field `Amount_formula` and use soql

> SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount_formula > USD5000